# Update view's frame keeping constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, constraints

Simply put, look at the pictures below:

1. I design a view, put the constraint to top left right bottom. It work correctly when change view orientation.

[image: Base]

2. Put a simple code to change the view height:

   // CODE

   ```
   -(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
   {
      self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

      CGRect updateViewFrame = self.updatingView.frame;
      updateViewFrame.size.height = textField.text.floatValue;
      self.updatingView.frame = updateViewFrame;

      [self.view setNeedsLayout];

      return YES;
    }
   ```

??? Why there's a mess with the code format in SO?

[image: Result]

What should I do **in the code** to make the UITextfield move up, along with the view's height, without changing the textField's frame directly?? My autolayout constraints doesn't work any longer after I change the view's frame.

Other notes:
1. The containerView is a scrollView, so no worry about the long height.
2. I ask if there's a way to work without directly change the UITextField's frame, because I'll add many more views, controls later. It may cause a mess if I have to update the frame for every single control there will be :(

Comment: You can use TPKeyboardAvoiding, https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: What does it has to do with keyboard? I want to update textField's frame according to the black view's height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create your autolayout constraints in Interface Builder, you can create `IBOutlets` for them, the same way as for views, buttons, etc. Than you can change the constant of such constraint and animate/refresh the view :

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *topSpace;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)someMethod {

    self.topSpace.constant = 60;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        [self.view layoutSubviews]; //just this line if you don't want the animation
    }];

}

@end
```

Setting the frame by hand breaks all constraints linked to that view.

Comment: So there's no other way but to mess up the frame directly? Setting the constant is also pretty much for me.....

Comment: No, there is a way - modify the constraint. What do you mean by "setting the constant is also pretty much for me"? Is it too hard? If so, why?

Comment: It's like, if I have too many views, I'll have to set that many constants, and that's what I meant by pretty much. Also, I've debugged yesterday, the top constraints outlet's constant is still the one I've set in IB, even though the frame has changed. Strange?

Comment: Well, it depends. Remember that if you change one constraint constant, the others will "adapt". But if you want to have a complicated (meaning lots of views) layout with a lot of animations and moving parts, maybe you'd be best with setting the constraints in code and using some kind of layout helper library like `Masonry` (https://github.com/SnapKit/Masonry) for example.